# how to install the latest version of rails on ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rubygems, rbenv

I want to install rails 3.2.1 on ubuntu 11.10.
I already installed rbenv, ruby-build.

When I run

```
gem install rails
```

it tells me

```
Successfully installed rails-3.2.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.2.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.2.1...
```

then after rbenv rehash, if I run "rails", it cannot find the binary file. So I guess rails is NOT installed. How can I do?

edit:

```
~ » gem environment                                                                                                                                                                                                                
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.15
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2011-10-30 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/jafar/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/jafar/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/jafar/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/jafar/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - /home/jafar/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

edit 2 :

gem list tells me the rails gem is installed. When I search for the rails binary I find this :

```
~ » find . -name rails
./.oh-my-zsh/plugins/rails
./Downloads/robbyrussell-oh-my-zsh-3629270/plugins/rails
./.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/guides/code/getting_started/script/rails
./.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/bin/rails
./.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails
./.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/generators/rails
./.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/script/rails
./.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/generators/rails/plugin_new/templates/rails
./.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-rails-3.2.4/test/fixtures/engine_project/script/rails
./.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-rails-3.2.4/test/fixtures/engine_project/test/dummy/script/rails
./.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-rails-3.2.4/test/fixtures/scss_project/script/rails
./.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-rails-3.2.4/test/fixtures/sass_project/script/rails
./.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-rails-3.2.4/lib/sass/rails
./.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-rails-3.2.4/lib/rails
./.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/rails
./.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionmailer-3.2.1/lib/rails
./.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jquery-rails-2.0.0/lib/jquery/rails
./.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.1.12/rails
./.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee/rails
./.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/rails
./.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin/rails
```

The rails binary should be in ~/.rbenv/shims but it's not. ~/.rbenv/shims is in my PATH

Comment: Did you install rbenv as root or for your user? How is it included in your .bashrc or .bash_profile? What's your gem environment (run `gem environment`)? Is the executable path included in your path?

Comment: rbenv is installed for my user and I added these lines in my .zshrc (since I use zsh) : export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH" 
eval "$(rbenv init -)"

Comment: So, run `gem environment` to see where the executable directory is - is that in your path? (run `echo $PATH). Also `gem list` should give you a list of gems that are installed. To me it sounds like rails is installed, but the executable isn't in your path.

Comment: The odd thing is that Rails 3.1.3 *does* seem to install a binary `l ~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-3.1.3/bin` is not empty while `l ~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-3.2.1/bin` is.

Comment: Whats the output of echo $PATH ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `bin` subdirectory of `/home/jafar/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1`  to your PATH, e.g. edit your `~/.bashrc` file and add this line at the end:
`export PATH=/home/jafar/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin:$PATH`

And then see what the command `rails --version` will output.